# what is a resolution of jiffie in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, timestamps

What is a resolution of jiffie in Linux Kernel?

according to current timer source (`cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource`), Linux uses TSC and has nanosecond resolution

according to http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/jiffies.h jiffie is not smaller than 1us, but can be larger.

Is there a way to determine its current resolution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you take a look at the man page `man 7 time`

> The value of HZ varies across kernel versions and hardware platforms. 
>   On i386 the situation is as follows: on  kernels  up  to  and 
>   including  2.4.x, HZ was 100, giving a jiffy value of 0.01 seconds;
>   starting with 2.6.0, HZ was raised to 1000, giving a jiffy of 0.001
>   seconds.  Since kernel 2.6.13, the HZ value is a kernel
>   configuration parameter and can be 100, 250 (the default) or 1000,
>   yielding a jiffies value of, respectively, 0.01, 0.004, or 0.001
>   seconds. Since kernel 2.6.20, a further frequency is available: 300, a
>   number that divides evenly for the common video frame rates (PAL, 25
>   HZ; NTSC, 30 HZ).
>
> The times(2) system call is a special case.  It reports times with a
>   granularity defined by the kernel con‐ stant  USER_HZ.    User-space
>   applications   can   determine   the   value   of   this   constant
>   using sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).

You can inquire the `CLK_TCK` constant:

```
$ getconf CLK_TCK
100
```

This tells you the value of HZ, i.e. 100. This value is the number of jiffies in a second.

#### References

- [How does USER_HZ solve the jiffy scaling issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410841/how-does-user-hz-solve-the-jiffy-scaling-issue)
- [time.h - time types](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html)

Comment: TL;DR: jiffy is hardware-dependent and kernel-version dependent. Correct ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy - correct

Comment: Unfortunately, this is wrong; `getconf CLK_TCK` always returns 100 on Linux systems; this has to do with the [`HZ` vs. `USER_HZ` hysterical raisin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17410841/2171120).

Answer (score 2):

According to these sources, the resolution for *jiffies* is `1/HZ` (whatever value `HZ` happens to have):

- [Linux kernel map in printable PDF for $4 or €3](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch10lev1sec3)
- [Kernel Timer Systems](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Timer_Systems)
- [kernel ticks, jiffies and high resolution timers...](http://sameerseth-tcp-ip.blogspot.com/2010/09/kernel-ticks-jiffies-and-high.html)

It is defined in one of the kernel-dependent header files, e.g.,

```
/usr/include/asm-generic/param.h
```

which is included from

```
/usr/include/linux/param.h
```

and ultimately from `<sys/param.h>`, which may be in an architecture-specific directory, e.g.,

```
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/param.h
```

The sources make it apparent that it is a compile-time constant and depends on your particular system.

Comment: sorry, I need to know "whatever value HZ happens to have" because I need to know the resolution of clock source in TCP and it is in jiffies