# `dd` is running at full speed, but I only see 20% disk utilization. Why?

Tags: linux, atop

1. `sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=1M iflag=direct`
2. `atopsar -d 5    # in a second terminal`
3. `top             # in a third terminal`

Results from `atopsar` :

```
19:18:32  disk           busy read/s KB/read  writ/s KB/writ avque avserv _dsk_
...
19:16:50  sda             18%  156.5  1024.0     0.0     0.0   5.0   1.15 ms
19:16:55  sda             18%  156.3  1024.0     0.0     0.0   4.9   1.15 ms
...
```

**Why is disk utilization ("busy") reported as much less than 100% ?**

According to `top`, the `dd` process only uses 3% of a CPU or less.  `top` also provides an overall report of hardware and software interrupt (`hi` and `si`) usage of the system's CPU's, which shows as less than 1%.  I have four CPUs (2 cores with 2 threads each).

`/dev/sda` is a SATA HDD.  It is not an SSD, it is not even a hybrid SSHD drive.  It cannot read faster than about 150 megabytes per second :-).  So that part of the results makes sense: 156 read/s * 1024 KB/read = 156 MB/s

The kernel version is `5.0.9-200.fc29.x86_64` (Fedora Workstation 29).  The IO scheduler is `mq-deadline`.  Since kernel version 5.0, Fedora uses the multi-queue block layer.  Because the single queue block layer has been removed :-).

I believe the disk utilization figure in `atopsar -d` and `atop` is calculated from one of the [kernel iostat fields](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/Documentation/iostats.txt).  The linked doc mentions "field 10 -- # of milliseconds spent doing I/Os".  There is a more detailed definition as well, although I am not sure that the functions it mentions still exist in the multi-queue block layer.  As far as I can tell, both `atopsar -d` and `atop` use [common code](https://github.com/Atoptool/atop/blob/v2.4.0/photosyst.c#L992) to read this field 10.  (I believe this field is also used by `sar -d` / `iostat -x` / `mxiostat.py`)

### Additional tests

Variant 2: Changing to `bs=512k`, but keeping `iflag=direct`.

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=512k iflag=direct`

```
19:18:32  disk           busy read/s KB/read  writ/s KB/writ avque avserv _dsk_
...
19:18:00  sda             35%  314.0   512.0     0.0     0.0   2.1   1.12 ms
19:18:05  sda             35%  313.6   512.0     0.2     4.0   2.1   1.11 ms
```

Variant 3: Using `bs=1M`, but removing `iflag=direct` . `dd` uses about 10% CPU, and 35% disk.

`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=1M`

```
19:18:32  disk           busy read/s KB/read  writ/s KB/writ avque avserv _dsk_
...
19:21:47  sda             35%  242.3   660.2     0.0     0.0   5.4   1.44 ms
19:21:52  sda             31%  232.3   667.8     0.0     0.0   9.5   1.33 ms
```

## How to reproduce these results - essential details

### Beware of the last test, i.e. running `dd` *without* `iflag=direct`

It is a bit of a hog.  I saw it freeze the system (mouse cursor) for ten seconds or longer.  Even when I had swap disabled.  (The test fills your RAM with [buff/cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440558/30-of-ram-is-buffers-what-is-it).  It is filling the inactive LRU list.  I think the turnover evicts inactive cache pages relatively quickly.  At the same time, the disk is busy with sequential reads, so it takes longer when you need to page something in.  How bad this gets probably depends on whether the kernel ends up also turning over the active LRU list, or shrinking it too much.  I.e. how well the current ["mash of a number of different algorithms with a number of modifications for catching corner cases and various optimisations"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281974/what-page-replacement-algorithms-are-used-in-linux-kernel-for-os-file-cache/282008) is working in your case).

### The *exact* results of the first test are difficult to reproduce.

Sometimes, `KB/read` shows as `512` instead of `1024`.  In this case, the other results look more like the results from `bs=512k`.  Including that it shows a disk utilization around 35%, instead of around 20%.  My question stands in either case.

If you would like to understand this behaviour, it is described here: [Why is the size of my IO requests being limited, to about 512K?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/529529/why-is-the-size-of-my-io-requests-being-limited-to-about-512k)

Comment: What's the output of  `ioptop` and `lshw`? And are you wondering why the maximum speed of the HDD @ 150MB/s is not 100%?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was the result of a change in kernel version 5.0:

> [block: delete part_round_stats and **switch to less precise counting**](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/5b18b5a73760)
>
> We want to convert to per-cpu in_flight counters.
>
> The function part_round_stats needs the in_flight counter every jiffy, it
> would be too costly to sum all the percpu variables every jiffy, so it
> must be deleted. part_round_stats is used to calculate two counters -
> time_in_queue and io_ticks.
>
> time_in_queue can be calculated without part_round_stats, by adding the
> duration of the I/O when the I/O ends (the value is almost as exact as the
> previously calculated value, except that time for in-progress I/Os is not
> counted).
>
> **io_ticks can be approximated by increasing the value when I/O is started
> or ended and the jiffies value has changed. If the I/Os take less than a
> jiffy, the value is as exact as the previously calculated value. If the
> I/Os take more than a jiffy, io_ticks can drift behind the previously
> calculated value.**

(`io_ticks` is used in [part_stat_show()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/block/partition-generic.c#L118), to provide the [kernel IO stat](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.0/Documentation/iostats.txt) for "field 10 -- # of milliseconds spent doing I/Os".)

This explains my results very nicely.  In the Fedora kernel configuration, a "[jiffy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240541/what-is-a-resolution-of-jiffie-in-linux-kernel)" is 1 millisecond.   I expect a large read IO submitted by `dd` can be pending for more than one or two jiffies.  Particularly on my system, which uses an old-fashioned mechanical HDD.

When I go back to the previous kernel series 4.20.x, it shows the correct disk utilization:

```
$ uname -r
4.20.15-200.fc29.x86_64
$ atopsar -d 5
...
13:27:19  disk           busy read/s KB/read  writ/s KB/writ avque avserv _dsk_
13:28:49  sda             98%  149.4  1024.0    13.0     5.3   2.2   6.04 ms
13:28:54  sda             98%  146.0  1024.0     7.2     5.7   1.5   6.38 ms
```

This old kernel used the legacy single-queue block layer, and the `cfq` IO scheduler by default.  The result is also the same when using the `deadline` IO scheduler.

---

Update: since kernel 5.7, this approximation is adjusted.  The command in the question shows 100% disk utilization again.  The new approximation is expected to break down for some more complex workloads (though I haven't noticed one yet).

> [block/diskstats: more accurate approximation of io_ticks for slow disks](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/2b8bd423614c595540eaadcfbc702afe8e155e50)
>
> Currently io_ticks is approximated by adding one at each start and end of
> requests if jiffies counter has changed. This works perfectly for requests
> shorter than a jiffy or if one of requests starts/ends at each jiffy.
>
> If disk executes just one request at a time and they are longer than two
> jiffies then only first and last jiffies will be accounted.
>
> Fix is simple: at the end of request add up into io_ticks jiffies passed
> since last update rather than just one jiffy.
>
> Example: common HDD executes random read 4k requests around 12ms.
>
> `fio --name=test --filename=/dev/sdb --rw=randread --direct=1 --runtime=30 &`
> `iostat -x 10 sdb`
>
> Note changes of iostat's "%util" 8,43% -> 99,99% before/after patch:
>
> Before:
>
> ```
> Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
> sdb               0,00     0,00   82,60    0,00   330,40     0,00     8,00     0,96   12,09   12,09    0,00   1,02   8,43
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s    rkB/s    wkB/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await r_await w_await  svctm  %util
> sdb               0,00     0,00   82,50    0,00   330,00     0,00     8,00     1,00   12,10   12,10    0,00  12,12  99,99
> ```
>
> Now io_ticks does not loose time between start and end of requests, but
> for queue-depth > 1 some I/O time between adjacent starts might be lost.
>
> For load estimation "%util" is not as useful as average queue length,
> but it clearly shows how often disk queue is completely empty.
>
> Fixes: 5b18b5a ("block: delete part_round_stats and switch to less precise counting") 
> Signed-off-by: Konstantin Khlebnikov <khlebnikov@yandex-team.ru> 
> Reviewed-by: Ming Lei <ming.lei@redhat.com> 
> Signed-off-by: Jens Axboe <axboe@kernel.dk>